# How do I expand objects from my live traced drawing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, live-trace

At the moment I am using CS5 Illustrator. 
When I make a drawing I draw by hand, ink it and then scan it. I just place in Illustrator then Live Trace and Expand.
My drawings always have many small parts that I have to separate from each other after using Expand.

What I have been doing is copying the drawing as many time because I have different objects and just Direct selection tool to remove everything on each copying files except one of each item on the drawing. I get the result I want but it takes a lot of time.

So the question is:
Is it a way to separate all the objects from each other in a faster way?

Thank you!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Expand the art work.

After using **Live Trace**, click the `Expand` button on the control bar.

After using **Live Paint**, click the `Expand` button on the control bar.

You may need to then **ungroup** via `Object > Ungroup`.

If things are still "connected" you can try `Object > Compound Path > Release`.

Answer (score 0):

After you expanded the shape/illustration everything is inside a group.

Use ctrl/cmd+shift+g  a couple of times and everything is a seperate object.

Comment: It did not work. And the Ungroup is blured in the Objekt drop down as well. Well, not blured but grey instead of black.

Comment: Can you describe the exact steps you tried? 'cause it works for me, so i find it quite odd it doesnt works for you.

Comment: Yes I´ll try:)
-Place.
-Live Trace (with one blur)
-Expand.
After that I juse the Live paint bucket to fill in the white with no fill.
And then I have the drawing that I want to split up.
Mabye I am doing something wrong? Most likely so:)

Comment: I am not familliar with live trace since i started illustrator since cs6. But I've been told that live trace and image trace are the same thing. Maybe if you do live paint after the ungrouping, maybe that works